# Thinking to using Netbeans as an IDE for JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to java and thinking to use netbeans as an IDE. Please update me that is it right choice for java intermediate developers? and is there any limitations of the using this IDE (netbeans)? Because some of my friends inform me that auto-generated code by Netbeans is read-only, not editable.

So, update me the merits and demerits of Netbeans so that I want to choose one IDE for long period of time.

Comment: `is there any limitations of the using this IDE` as I know only knowledge about Java PL is alyways limi...

Comment: Let me be biased (since I have worked on Eclipse and NetBeans, JDevloper, JBuilder, and many other flavours): Use Eclipse, if you don't want to grow grey hairs too quickly, lol. If you're too **techy**, use **Vi** editor (*evil laugh*) :-D

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman and this is how you become  `Let me be biased (since I have worked on Eclipse and NetBeans): Use Eclipse, if you don't want to grow grey hairs too quickly, lol.` not really not never :-) just joke I can't resist :-)

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman - I am using `Notepad` and I have no hair left, LOL:P

Comment: @Petar Minchev, LMAO...you're a lost hope, I'm afraid. Well, it's not too late to start using Eclipse. :-D

Comment: This question is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413500/eclipse-or-netbeans) of a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308450/netbeans-or-eclipse-for-c) of a [question closed as not contructive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765608/netbeans-or-eclipse).

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of IDEs available for Java development (Eclipse, MyEclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ Idea, JBuilder X, etc.), and there are pros and cons to usage of all. You need to decide what's best based on your project and application requirements.

Check out this - http://faq.programmerworld.net/programming/best-java-ide-review.html - for a good info on the evaluation of these IDEs.

Comment: it looks like a pretty old review - Eclipse (reviewed at 3.0) is now on 3.7 and each 0.1 in between was a pretty big increment......

Comment: @mikera - yes, that's true (and may be there are other recent evaluations, that am not aware of). But i think for a beginner like him, this is a good starting point to decide on which to go for.

Answer (score 2):

If you are at very beginning of Java spend some hours with a plain text editor and the Java tools *java* and *javac*. Then use *ant* for building some lesson projects, still with plain text editor. If you feel comfortable with that, switch to an IDE. Not so important which one, but NB runs most things out-of-the-box. With your knowledge from the first steps you will quick understand the structure and backgrounds of the IDE's. For advanced users it is very common to use more than one IDE, depending on projects requirements.

Comment: sorry, but am not convinced why would you want to use plain text editors in today's world (breaking your head in avoiding silly typos, missing imports and so on), when you have (so many) convenient IDEs at your service. Learning  java and javac is a totally different deal, and I think it out of context here.

Comment: nobody is recommending this as an overall development approach, but it's not a bad idea to try this once or twice just so that you know exactly what the IDEs is doing for you "under the hood". For example, it will teach you what a .class file is, the handling of which is hidden by most IDEs......

Comment: I said **some** hours ! to avoid such questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176902/how-do-i-run-a-jar-executable-java-file-from-outside-netbeans-ide when basic deployment get a problem ...

Answer (score 2):

Except for IBM's WSAD, everything else is good. I use Netbeans, Eclipse, JDeveloper. It really depends on the frameworks you are working with, database, middleware and source control. If NB supports all of them then go for it. It works very well with open source components and with JavaScript. Also, it provides a better out of the box integration than Eclipse. Eclipse is a little complicated. Although I have been using Eclipse since the day it was launched, the user interface is too busy for my liking. It's an individual preference really. IntelliJ's paid version is also one of my favorites.